# sending file using UDP multicast

Tags: java, udp, multicast

I have a problem where I want to send my file to my friend using UDP multicast, but when I try to run the code the output is this:

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal length or offset
    at java.net.DatagramPacket.setData(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramPacket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Source.createConnection(Source.java:44)
    at Source.main(Source.java:102)
```

And this is my code:

```
 import java.io.*;

    import java.net.*;
    public class Source {
    private DatagramSocket socket = null;
    private FE event = null;
    private String sourceFilePath = "C:/joe's/file/text/hai.txt";
    private String destinationPath = "C:/maria/file2/laboratory/";
    private String hostname= "192.168.43.65";

    public Source(){ }
    public static void main1(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();

            byte[]line = new byte[100];

            System.out.print("Enter text to send");
            int len = System.in.read(line);
            InetAddress dest = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.65");

            DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(line,len,dest,16900);

            s.send(pkt);
            s.close();
        }

    catch(Exception err){
        System.err.println(err);

    }
    }

    public void createConnection() {

    try {
    socket = new DatagramSocket();

    byte[] incomingData = new byte[9999];
    event = getFE();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    os.writeObject(event);

    byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, 9876);
    socket.send(sendPacket);
    System.out.println("File sent from AppsA");

    DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, 
    incomingData.length);
    socket.receive(incomingPacket);
    String response = new String(incomingPacket.getData());
    System.out.println("Response from AppsB:" + response);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.exit(0); 
    }

 catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }



 public FE getFE() {
 FE fileEvent = new FE();
 String fileName = sourceFilePath.substring(sourceFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, 
 sourceFilePath.length());
 String path = sourceFilePath.substring(0, sourceFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    fileEvent.setDestinationDirectory(destinationPath);

    fileEvent.setFilename(fileName);
    fileEvent.setSourceDirectory(sourceFilePath);
    File file = new File(sourceFilePath);
    if (file.isFile())
 {
    try {
    DataInputStream diStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    long len = (int) file.length();
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) len];
    int read = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (read < fileBytes.length && (numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read,
    fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0) {
    read = read + numRead;
    }

    fileEvent.setFileSize(len);
    fileEvent.setFileData(fileBytes);
    fileEvent.setStatus("Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    fileEvent.setStatus("Error");
    }
    }

 else {
    System.out.println("path specified is not pointing to a file");
    fileEvent.setStatus("Error");
    }
    return fileEvent;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Source app = new Source();
    app.createConnection();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please format this to be readable and show some steps as to what you've done to fix the issue.

Comment: You need to go back to the Javadoc for `DatagramPacket` and carefully read the descriptions and argument lists for the various constructors.  It looks like you are confusing port numbers with offset/length.  Also, the no-arg constructor for `DatagramSocket` binds to a random port, so you will need to `getLocalPort()` if you want to send to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in improper use of DatagramPacket constructors:

```
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, 9876);
```

The above line is correct however, the code below:

```
DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, 
incomingData.length);
```

Should be this:

```
DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, 
9876);
```

The second argument in the DatagramPacket constructor is the length.  You initially set the length on sendPacket to 9876